# Does it matter which database you connect to when querying across multiple databases?

Tags: sql-server, connection-string, multiple-database

I'm building a Sharepoint application with Nintex workflow that runs a single SQL query over multiple databases (on the same MS SQL server). Does it matter which database I specify in the connection string in terms of speed?
So if my query looks like this:
`SELECT col1, col2 FROM db1.table UNION ALL`
`SELECT col1, col2 FROM db2.table UNION ALL`
`SELECT col1, col2 FROM db3.table`

would it make any difference if my connection string looks like this:
`Server=***;Database=db1; Integrated Security=SSPI; Connection Timeout=900`
or this
`Server=***;Database=db2; Integrated Security=SSPI; Connection Timeout=900`
or this?
`Server=***;Database=db3; Integrated Security=SSPI; Connection Timeout=900`

The table from db1 has more records than db2, which has more records than db3.

EDIT: My query is actually more complex than what I wrote above, I just simplified it because I didn't know that would matter. The real queries have a `WHERE` clause and a `LEFT JOIN` on a fourth database (db4).
The compatibility level of db2 and db3 are `SQL Server 2008 (100)`, for db1 and db4 it's `SQL Server 2017 (140)`.

Answer (score 4):

In your example there is no difference.

But there can be difference if your query is more complicated, has parameters and the databases have different `compatibility level`/`parameterization` options.

`Compatibility level` of the database where the query is executed will affect cardinality estimations, so if your predicates contain `AND` `OR` conditions the estimated number of rows will be calculated according to different optimizator's rules, there are cases when someone migrates to a new server (say 2014) but leaves user databases compatibility level 100, in this case in he executes the query in the `master`'s context new 2014 optimizator will do calculations, but if he executes the same query in user database the legacy optimizator will do estimations and they will differ.

Also `forced parameterization` can affect the plan.

If your query contain `joins` and constants in `where` filter, these constants will be preserved when estimation is done if database has `simple parameterization`, so the estimation will use statistics for filtering field.
But if the same query is executed in the context of database with `forced parameterization` the query will be parameterized and the plan will be built by using unknown value for the filter.

Comment: Thanks, that already cleared it up a bit. My query is actually more complex than what I wrote above, I just simplified it because I didn't know that would matter. The real queries have a WHERE clause and a LEFT JOIN on a fourth database (db4).  
The compatibility level of db2 and db3 are SQL Server 2008 (100), for db1 and db4 it's SQL Server 2017 (140). So would it be best to connect to db1 then, since it has the highest compatibility level?

Comment: You should test it by executing it from db with c.l. 100 and c.l. 140 and comparing the actual execution plans. Some queries can be faster with the legacy estimations, some with newest, and there can be no difference at all, it's impossible to guess without comparing the actual plans

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the databases has the same compatibility level, then the performance shuuld be the same.

However, compat level also determine performance related stuff (the CE, whether you have access to new features in the optimizer etc) and with this in mind I believe that the source database could affect performance. However, doing straight SELECT * without a WHERE clause, there isn't much the optimizer can do. Possibly batch mode on rowstore if you are on 2019.